# Python: Как передать значение полученное функции 1 в функцию 2

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день всем читающим! 
Я новичок-автотестер, прошу помочь со следующей проблемой:

Есть следующая функция:

```
def check_and_select_row (cls, grid, number, date):
    query = sql_query('''select [name] from [ref].[Departments]''')
    main_grid = Driver.get().find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="invoiceJournalGrid"]/div[@class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable"]/table//tbody/tr')
    x = 1
    y = 0
    number = 0
    date = 0
    for status_check in main_grid:
        while y < len(query):
            if (cls.get_grid_values('Status', x, grid,
                                          mode='get_value') != 'Изъята' and cls.get_grid_values(
                'DestDepartment', x, grid, mode='get_value') not in query[y]):
                cls.get_grid_values('DestDepartment', x, grid, mode='click')
                y += 1
                number = cls.get_grid_values('OutgoingNumber', x, grid, mode='get_value')
                date = cls.get_grid_values('DocDate', x, grid, mode='get_value')
            else:
                y = 0
                x += 1
    return number, date
```

В переменную number и date записываются значения выбранного столбца, столбец выбирается согласно условиям выше

Далее эти значения мне нужно использовать в функции 2:

```
def check_expedition_report(cls, number, date):
    check_status = 0
    check_department = 0
    for el in Driver.get().find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="textLayer"]/*'):
        if number in el.text:
            check_status = 1
    for el in Driver.get().find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="textLayer"]/*'):
        if date in el.text:
            check_department = 1
```

где у меня производится проверка отчета на наличие значений переменных, извлеченных из функции 1

Вопрос, как исправить код таким образом, чтобы это работало? Спасибо!

Comment: `number, date = check_and_select_row(...)`, `check_expedition_report(cls, number, date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `check_and_select_row` возвращает 2 значения. Вы можете сохранить эти 2 значения в отдельные переменные. Синтаксис:

```
number, date = check_and_select_row(...)
```

Далее эти переменные можно передать в следующую функцию

```
check_expedition_report(cls, number, date)
```

Если хотите результат из первой функции сразу передать в качестве аргумента во вторую, то

```
check_expedition_report(cls, *check_and_select_row(...))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейТиньков На StackOverflow есть возможность отметить правильный ответ, который помог, галочкой :)